# How to call another method with a method as parameter when the referenced method throws an exception?

Tags: java, exception

I've seen couple of examples of this but unfortunately none where the method throws an exception.

To be clear, there is one generic method I have that receives another method as reference.

This method throws an exception on its method's signature, when this method (returnFullName in the example) does not throw an Exception no problem for the compiler, but when it does the compiler complains "**Unhandled exception"**.

I still cannot figure out how to solve this, is there any idea how to handle the exceptions in these cases?

```
public class MyClass{
    private  static String returnFullName(String name) throws Exception{
            return "full name " + name;
        }

        public static String calculateByName(String name) {
            try {
                myGenericMethod("John Doe", RemoteFileUtils::returnFullName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "fallback name";
            }
        }

         private static <T> T myGenericMethod(final String name, final Function<String, T> call) {
            //do stuff
            return call.apply(name);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to catch the exception that may be thrown by `returnFullName`. It must be caught in the implementation of the `Function` you are passing to `myGenericMethod` :

```
    public static String calculateByName(String name) {
        return myGenericMethod("John Doe", t -> {
            try {
                return returnFullName (t);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "fallback name";
            }
        });
    }
```

Wrapping the `myGenericMethod("John Doe", RemoteFileUtils::returnFullName);` call with a try-catch block doesn't help, since `myGenericMethod` is not the method that may throw the exception.

Comment: yes, I just found out but this is the correct answer, thanks!